# SSL VALIDATION FAILED [SSL: WRONG_VERSION NUMBER] error in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-textract

i am trying to access aws s3 or textract on remote computer(VDI) of my company. it uses some kind of proxy too. while accessing the remote computer i am getting these error and it is fine while accessing via my personal computer. i have to contact system admin to fix this, i am not sure what to do.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to answer the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.